# How to display edge seams and sharps in Blender 3.6.0?

Tags: uv, edit-mode, seams

In Blender 3.3.1 "edge seams" and "edge sharp" would appear red and cyan in edit mode respectively, if one is in edit mode with edge selection activated.

Looks like in Blender 3.6.0 is no longer like this.
Do you know what lead to this design decision?

Is there a workaround to display seams and sharps again?

Comment: Blender 3.6 here. I see cyan (sharp) and red (seam) edges. In `Edit > Preferences > Themes > 3D Viewport` you can change the displayed colors under `Edge Seam` and `Edge Sharp`. Maybe you imported some weird old settings?

Comment: They are exactly the same in 3.6 as they are in 3.5 and all previous versions right back to 2.8.3 (the earliest version I have installed) here.

Comment: Maybe this is a issue in Linux? Ubuntu 22.04 here. Downloaded Blender 3.5.0 and Blender 3.6.1 and the problem persists. Loaded and saved factory settings do not fixed the issue. And there is more! UPGE which is based on Blender 3.6.0 displays seams and sharps correctly!

Comment: And I also run Blender 3.6.1 Windows via Wine and it displays seams and sharps too!

Comment: https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/110640

Comment: @chicOrtiz Your issue was closed because it is a duplicate of this one: https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/109780